# Não consigo fazer média

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Não estou conseguindo fazer a soma entre a qtd_itens_compra com o count cod_pessoa.  A query roda normal,  na frequenciacompra o resultado apresentado é o mesmo da quantia de itens que vem do "qtd_itens_compra". Em resumo, gostaria de somar todos os itens e dividir pela quantia de pessoas, pegando o cod_pessoa.

```
select top 10 cod_pessoa as CodPessoa,
            dat_compra as DataCompra,   
            vlr_compra as ValorCompra,
            cod_transacao as CodigoTransacao,       

            sum(qtd_itens_compra)/count(cod_pessoa)as FrequenciaCompra 

 from tab_transacao
 where dat_compra between '2017-08-01' and '2018-08-01'
 group by cod_pessoa,
          dat_compra,   
          vlr_compra,
          cod_transacao
```

Comment: não entendi bem, mas o `sum`e o `count` vão acompanhar os agrupamento, ou seja, para a combinação codpessoa,datacompra,valor,compra,codtransacao. Se precisar de cálculo "geral" não vai funcionar numa única query

Comment: O @RicardoPontual tem razão, ambas as funções acompanham o `GROUP BY`, logo a sua _query_ não vai funcionar como pretende. Porquê o `TOP 10`?

Comment: Top 10 era só a troco de teste, precisava chegar num resultado da soma de todos meus itens, com a quantia total de pessoas que eu tenho.

Comment: Sendo assim a solução que apresentei abaixo deveria funcionar corretamente. Não lhe devolve o valor que pretendia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua `query` você está agrupando por valor da compra, o que acaba sendo errado, já que pelo que entendi você quer a frequência de compra por dia. Ajustando sua `query` ficaria assim:

```
SELECT cod_pessoa AS CodPessoa,
      dat_compra AS DataCompra,
      cod_transacao AS CodigoTransacao,
      SUM(qtd_itens_compra) / COUNT(cod_pessoa) AS FrequenciaCompra
  FROM tab_transacao
WHERE dat_compra BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2018-08-01'
GROUP BY dat_compra,
          cod_transacao
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma função específica para médias em SQL, `AVG`:

```
SELECT      cod_pessoa              AS CodPessoa
        ,   dat_compra              AS DataCompra
        ,   vlr_compra              AS ValorCompra
        ,   cod_transacao           AS CodigoTransacao
        ,   AVG(qtd_itens_compra)   AS FrequenciaCompra 
FROM        tab_transacao
WHERE       dat_compra BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2018-08-01'
GROUP BY    cod_pessoa
        ,   dat_compra
        ,   vlr_compra
        ,   cod_transacao
```

Comment: Eu precisava somar a quantia de itens e dividir pela quantia de pessoa.

Comment: João, se der uma lida na pergunta acho que ele não quer  a média da de "qtd_itens_compra" diretamente, acho q precisa de uma soma parcial para depois o `avg`, isso pelo q eu entendi

Comment: Coloquei assim porque na questão ele colocou `SUM(qtd_itens_compra)`.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer a soma total, dividida pelo `count` parcial (agrupado), você pode usar uma subquery (veja se a performace fica boa):

```
select top 10 cod_pessoa as CodPessoa,
            dat_compra as DataCompra,   
            vlr_compra as ValorCompra,
            cod_transacao as CodigoTransacao,       
            (select sum(qtd_itens_compra) from tab_transacao)/count(cod_pessoa)as FrequenciaCompra 
 from tab_transacao
 where dat_compra between '2017-08-01' and '2018-08-01'
 group by cod_pessoa,
          dat_compra,   
          vlr_compra,
          cod_transacao
```

Comment: Realmente funcionou, mas o resultado me parece diferente do que preciso.
a coluna FrequenciaCompra gerou o seguinte resultado:
FrequenciaCOmpra:
485025.000000
485025.000000
485025.000000
485025.000000
485025.000000
485025.000000
485025.000000
485025.000000
485025.000000
485025.000000
Me parece errado, não? Pois na qtd_itens_compra, existem valores variados.

Comment: Isso depende do count, coloque antes do calculo da frequencia o count pra ver o valor: `count(cod_pessoa) contagem,` se o valor for o mesmo para cada agrupamento, o cálculo da frequencia estará certo, e o problema pode ser no agrupamento

Comment: Fiz a inversão, o resultado foi diferente do outro:

 (select count(qtd_itens_compra) from tab_transacao)/sum(vlr_compra)as FrequenciaCompra

Comment: ah não era uma inversão acho q não expliquei bem.. rs
era só pra adicionar isso na query, só para ver qto estava contando